# Is there any way of automating the startup of applications on virtual desktops on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, automation, virtual-desktop

Every time I start my computer I need to go to each different virtual desktop that I have and start the applications that I usually use on that virtual desktop, this is specially cumbersome for me because I use two monitors and I need to start two applications per virtual desktop for each monitor and then drag them to the correct monitor.

Is there any way I can automate this task?

Comment: Are these the Task Views you are talking about? What build of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest build. I guess they are task views.